# how to solve this problem of liner equation in two variable

Tags: linear-algebra

in **NCERT** **Exampler**, pg: 34, question: 10,

> A railway half ticket costs half the full fare, but the reservation
>   charges are the same on a half ticket as on a full ticket. One
>   reserved first class ticket from the station A to B costs Rs 2530.
>   Also, one reserved first class ticket and one reserved first class
>   half ticket from A to B costs Rs 3810. Find the full first class fare
>   from station A to B, and also the reservation charges for a ticket

in this question i got the first equation:

> x + y = 2530

where y is the reservation cost and x is the cost of full ticket

and may be this is wrong because i don't understand this question clearly

but i couldn't find the second equation so to solve this question. and the answer is `y = 30`

thanks.

Comment: comone please answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, define the variables:**

- $x=$ full ticket charge
- $y=$ reservation charge

**Then, define the equations:**

- $x+y=2530$
- $(x+y)+(\frac{1}{2}x+y)=3810$

**Finally, solve the equation-system:**

- $x=2500$
- $y=30$

Comment: please explain the second equation

Comment: @anni: [full ticket charge + reservation charge] + [half ticket charge + reservation charge] is $3810$.